# code to determine when something repeats 100 times in a row in r

Tags: r

I am working with data that is collected at 100Hz (100 samples per second) and need to cut data at the beginning when the device collected a partial second.  I pulled out the seconds from the timestamp and made it its own column. An example of my data looks like

```
Seconds
19
19
19
19
19
20
20
20
...Continue until there are 100 samples at 20 seconds, then switch to 21
```

I am looking for code that will cut off those '19' seconds (first 5 numbers) so my first second of data will contain all 100 samples. I am trying to work with functions that look for something to repeat 100 times in a row but unsure if thats the best method.

Thanks.

Comment: `?rle` ........

Comment: This would probably be easier to understand if you included at least two columns from your data file.

Comment: What's the format of your data file? Is it a CSV? Something else?

Comment: It is being read in as a .csv file.  Its a data.frame in R.

Other columns in the file are acceleration data.  I am deleting the acceleration data that is collected before the first full second so the time stamps on all of my files start on the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First decide if you need to cut anything off at the start by seeing if there are fewer instances of the first second count than expected:

```
nsec = 100
nfirsts = which.min(df$seconds == df$seconds[1])-1
cutme = nfirsts < nsec
```

then act:

```
if(cutme){
  df = df[(nfirsts+1):nrow(df),,drop=FALSE]
}
```

Here's a function:

```
chop_start = function(d, col,  n){
 nfirsts = which.min(d[[col]] == d[[col]][1])-1
 if(nfirsts < n){
  return(d[(nfirsts-1):nrow(d),,drop=FALSE])
 }
 return(d)
}
```

Use like:

```
df = chop_start(df, "seconds", 100)
```

Edit: don't do the same thing twice

Edit2: this might be quicker if `which.min` stops at the first `FALSE` value without scanning the whole data frame.

Comment: This worked perfectly!  Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Only the first 100 records need to be checked - not the whole dataframe.

Comment: @ngm good point, can probably change the test to `which.min(d[[col]][1:n] == d[[col]][1])` - look out for edge cases like `d` not having >100 rows though...

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps get you on the right track!

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(seconds = c(rep(19, 5), rep(20, 100), rep(21, 100)))

df %>%
  group_by(seconds) %>%
  filter(n() ==100) %>%
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 200 x 1
#>    seconds
#>      <dbl>
#>  1      20
#>  2      20
#>  3      20
#>  4      20
#>  5      20
#>  6      20
#>  7      20
#>  8      20
#>  9      20
#> 10      20
#> # ... with 190 more rows
```